# intersection of plane elliptic curve with coordinate hyperplanes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E: y^2z = x^3 - Axz^2 - Bz^3$ be a plane elliptic curve. I want to calculate the intersection of $E$ with the coordinate hyperplanes $H_i = \{x_i = 0\}$, $i=1,2,3$.  I write $H_x = \{x=0\}, H_y = \{y=0\}, H_z = \{z=0\}$.

Let $0 = [0:1:0]$ be the point at infinity and $E[2]$ be the $2$-torsion.

We have $E \cap H_y = E[2] \setminus \{0\}$ and $E \cap H_z = \{0\}$ (with multiplicity 3).  For $E \cap H_x$, we get $\{0\} \cup \{[0:\pm\sqrt{B}:1]\}$.

Now my question is: What is the order of the points $[0:\pm\sqrt{B}:1]$ in $E(k)$?

Comment: I thought this holds true for $[*:0:1]$.

Comment: Oops! Very careless of me, and I’ve deleted that comment. The truth is that nothing whatever can be said about the order of such a point. It can be $2$, $3$, or anything. Examples: $y^2=x^3-x$ and $y^2=x^3+1$ for the $2$ and the $3$. And need I say that you should expect that a point of that form would be of infinite order?